# How can I build Google App Enging Java SDK?

Tags: java, ant, google-app-engine

I have downloaded the source code of Google App Engine and I would like to change the behavior of some methods (for example, `DatastoreService.put(Entity e)`) used in this [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Writing_Datastore_and_memcache_tests):

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import static com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class LocalDatastoreTest {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }

    // run this test twice to prove we're not leaking any state across tests
    private void doTest() {
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        assertEquals(0, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
        ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
        ds.put(new Entity("yam"));
        assertEquals(2, ds.prepare(new Query("yam")).countEntities(withLimit(10)));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert1() {
        doTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsert2() {
        doTest();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not see that the build.xml file provided with the source code makes any compilation of the source `.java` files. For example, when I add some garbage to one of the source files and try to build the SDK using `ant dist` it returns BUILD SUCCESSFUL rather than a compile time error.

Any ideas where can I find the source file of the put(Entity e) method? and how can I compile the source code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make any changes to App Engine SDK. SDK exposes methods that are directly related to and dependent upon the internal operations of the App Engine and its Datastore. You are not supposed to compile the SDK separately from your source code.

Comment: But, why did they share the source code in the first place?

Comment: In some cases it may be useful to take a look inside and understand what is happening. The community may also help with fixing bugs or suggesting improvements.